# After Sort in Python how to create new Index field

Tags: sorting, indexing

After I sort my data, I am trying to create a new index field.

Here is my code:

```
    mydata_1=[[38,125,56],[98,23,150],[11,46,15],[23,87,81]]            
    cols= ['Col_A','Col_B','Col_C']          
    mydata_2= pd.DataFrame(mydata_1, columns=cols)
    mydata_3= mydata_2.sort('Col_A')
```

So with my code above the output looks like this:

```
       Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
    2     11     46     15
    3     23     87     81
    0     38    125     56
    1     98     23    150
```

I need to create a new column called "Col_D" as seen below:

```
       Col_A  Col_B  Col_C  Col_D
    2     11     46     15      1
    3     23     87     81      2
    0     38    125     56      3
    1     98     23    150      4
```

Also, I am going to be using this on many data sets. Is there a way to do this without specifying a range?

Comment: Its not really clear how you want to fill column D.  Given what logic will column D be filled?

Comment: Well, that's what I was hoping to find out. I need to create a new column of sequential values. How can I do this?

Comment: Nevermind, I get what your asking for. After you sort by column A you just want a new column that is auto incremented to use as an index. Ok, one min, i'll post a solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
import pandas as pd

mydata_1=[[38,125,56],[98,23,150],[11,46,15],[23,87,81]]            
cols= ['Col_A','Col_B','Col_C']          
mydata_2= pd.DataFrame(mydata_1, columns=cols)
mydata_3= mydata_2.sort('Col_A')   
mydata_3["Col_D"] = range(len(mydata_3.index))
print(mydata_3)
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)